# Excel and selecting variables conditionally

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set which contains information by country. For example, Australia_F is the observation for Australia and Australia_Weight is the weight of Australia. Each period, represents a specific year.

```
Period Australia_F Canada_F Denmark_F Japan_F Australia_Weight Canada_Weight Denmark_Weight Japan_weight
 1985     0.05     -0.02     0.02     0.03         0.10           0.30           0.45           0.15
 1986     -0.04    -0.03     0.02     0.01         0.15           0.30            0.30          0.25
```

The user can input any value to the following cell. For example I have inserted 3

```
Weight_Modification = 3
```

- The goal is to only include countries where the variable XXXXX_F are positive
- and use those with the highest values such that the total weight of counties selected is not greater than 1.
- The problem is complicated by the fact that the weight_modification variable, multiplies each individual county weight by whatever the value is. For example, the Weight for Australia would be 0.10 *3 = 0.3 in 1985.
- Total weights can be less than 1.00 but can't be greater than 1.00

So taking the above data as an example and for 1985 the results would be

```
Australia_weight Canada_weight Denmark_weight Japan_weight Total_weight
      0.3                                        0.45            0.75
```

- This is because in 1985 Australia has the highest value (Australia_F = 0.05), followed by Japan (Japan_F = 0.03).
- Each countries weights are multiplied by 3.
- Denmark is not selected even through Denmark_F is positive, because including Denmark the total weight exceeds 1.

In the actual file there are many more countries (12 in total) and many years.

Any help with how to put this together in excel is greatly appreciated.

Comment: the requirements are so complex VBA code may be easier (if you have any knowledge of how to program).

Comment: What do you mean by "select" when you say "The goal is to select.."? You mean, to put a visual cue like highlight it or select it to isolate it later?

Comment: @SpaghettiCode by "select" I mean if the value meets the criteria then use the value

Comment: @ScottHoltzman.. unfortunately I don't know VBA. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Is the layout flexible? I mean can we add some columns? Without doing so, I think, we will encounter circular reference errors. There must be additional columns to hold the new data.

Comment: @SpaghettiCode, there are no restrictions on columns. Happy to add anything.

Comment: If that's the case, then what's stopping you from creating helper columns?